# associative arrays-Display key values with image slider

Tags: javascript, html, associative-array

I'm working on designing a website and have an image slider displaying 20 images.

```
var slideimages = new Array()
slideimages[0] = new Image()
slideimages[0].src = "Stadium Images/anfield.jpg"
slideimages[1] = new Image()
slideimages[1].src = "Stadium Images/britannia.jpg"
slideimages[2] = new Image()
slideimages[2].src = "Stadium Images/oldtrafford.jpg"

<img src = "anfield.jpg" name = "slide" id = "slide" width  ="500px"        height = "300px">
    <script type= "text/javascript">
    var step=0
    function slideit()
    {
        document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
        if (step<19)
            step++
        else
            step=0
            setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
    }
        slideit()
    </script>
```

I want to make this an associative array where the key in the array is a string of the name of the stadiums and this will change with the change of image. Problem is if I change to an associative array and put in key values this will stop my image slider as you can see with the step variable I am using this is how the method is switching images. Any ideas on if I switch this to an associative how I get the images and keys(which I will display in a h3/h4) to work together

Thanks

Comment: So you simply want to use an object?

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust the initiation and the "indexes":

```
var slideimages = {}
slideimages["anfield"] = new Image()
slideimages["anfield"].src = "Stadium Images/anfield.jpg"
slideimages["britannia"] = new Image()
slideimages["britannia"].src = "Stadium Images/britannia.jpg"
slideimages["oldtrafford"] = new Image()
slideimages["oldtrafford"].src = "Stadium Images/oldtrafford.jpg"
```